# Dual boot windows 10 and linux on seperate drive

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, multi-boot

So, I have 2 drives on my laptop: they are a 250GB SSD and a 1TB HDD, and Windows 10 is already installed on the SSD.

I want to install Debian 9.7 on my HDD and it is already partitioned, with 3 partitions.

```
C: win 10 main OS  (SSD)

D: empty partition (HDD) -> here where i want to install debian

E: my personal data(HDD)

F: my personal data(HDD)
```

My question is how to install it correctly?

Comment: It should work if you don't touch the SSD.  When you install Debian, install GRUB on the HDD.  It will find Windows on your system and include it in its boot selections.  Then give the HDD a higher boot priority in the BIOS.  You will be able to get to either OS from GRUB (if you pick Windows, GRUB will direct the boot to the SSD).  The SSD/Windows won't be affected (if you remove the HDD, it will boot Windows from the SSD).  BTW, carve out a swap partition on the HDD and consider also putting /home in a separate partition on the HDD (personal data).

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be to try to install Debian and see how it works.

I have Windows + Ubuntu on separate drives, so it is really possible and easy to do.

You could just try to boot Debian installer and see if you can choose preferred partition for it in the setup. You may need to play with BIOS a little - perhaps change boot order to boot Debian setup from flash drive, or change boot order for drives for when both OSes are installed. You may also try to disable Windows drive on BIOS (if that's possible on your BIOS) while installing Debian.

After successful installation, find (search on the internet) the key that you need to press when PC is just turned on to bring the boot menu. For me it is F12. It allows to choose which PHYSICAL (not a partition) drive to boot from that time. So I press F12 every time I turn on my PC to select which OS I want.